# Unity Container, Interface infinite loop

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container, containers

I need help with configuring MS Unity.

I have a class implementing an interface:

```
public class ProjectService : IProjectService
```

which works fine with this configuration:

```
_conainer.RegisterType<IProjectService, ProjectService>();
```

I another, caching, implementation, I need the first concrete type injected into the caching concrete type.

```
public class CachedProjectService : IProjectService
{
    public CachedProjectService(IProjectService projectService, ICacheStorage cacheStorage)
    {}
}
```

How can I configure Unity to return the caching version with the first implementation injected into it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called decorators wiring that you can achieve like this :

```
_container.RegisterType<IProjectService, ProjectService>("innerService");

_container.RegisterType<IProjectService, CachedProjectService>(
    new InjectionConstructor(
        new ResolvedParameter<IProjectService>("innerService"), 
        new ResolvedParameter<ICacheStorage>()
    ));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: PERFECT Thomas... Right on the spot!

Comment: Just started on IoC and its great... :)

Comment: I would advice a great book then : http://www.manning.com/seemann/. Really really good.